# Best way to "hold" access to users other sites

Tags: security, api

I am playing with an idea that would allow people to add tickets to unfuddle, post a message to twitter/facebook etc. all from the one site.  To do this I need their username/password for these other sites but I don't really want to know that information.  Is there another way of achieving the same thing without having to holding this kind of information, going through a trusted third part site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of sites offer APIs, and you should use these - in some cases, they will issue you with a token to say not only have they authenticated, but they allow you to impersonate them.

Comment: What keywords should I look for in the API to know if they provide this authentication and what might the process be for users to link each of these services to my site.  I'm sure someone has already done this!